# Trigger WebJob at a particular time after record added to a database

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I want to trigger an Azure Webjob 24Hours after I have added a record to a database using .NET . Obviously there will be multiple tasks for the Webjob to handle, all at their designated time. Is there a way ( in the Azure Library for .NET) in which i can schedule this tasks ?

I am free to use Message Queues , but I want to try and avoid the unnecessary polling of the WebJob for new messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the event of adding a record to the database is the trigger here, You can use Azure Management Libraries to create a Azure Scheduler Job to execute after 24hrs from the time the db record is inserted. Azure Scheduler Jobs can do only 3 things : make HTTP/HTTPS requests or Put Message in Queue. Since you do not want to poll queues, here are two options

1. Deploy the existing Web Job as Wep API where each task is reachable by unique URLs, so that the scheduler task can execute the right HTTP/HTTPS request
2. Create a new WebAPI/Wep API which takes accepts request (like a man in the middle) and pro-grammatically run the existing web job on demand, again using Azure management libraries.

Please let me know if any of these strategies help.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to trigger the execution of a WebJob 24 hours after a record insertion in a SQL database I would definitely use Azure Queues for this. So after you insert the record, just add a message to the queue.

In order to do this you can easily leverage the `initialVisibilityDelay` property that can be passed to the `CloudQueue.AddMessage()` method. This will make the message invisible for 24 hours in your case, and then it will appear to be processed by your Webjob. You don't have to schedule anything, just have a Continuous WebJob listening to a queue running.

Here's some sample code:

```
public void AddMessage(T message, TimeSpan visibilityDelay)
{
    var serializedMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
    var queue = GetQueueReference(message);
    queue.AddMessage(new CloudQueueMessage(serializedMessage), null, visibilityDelay);
}

private static CloudQueue GetQueueReference(T message)
{
    var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("Insert connection string");
    var queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
    var queueReference = queueClient.GetQueueReference("Insert Queue Name");

    queueReference.CreateIfNotExists();
    return queueReference;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Although all answers lead me down correct paths, using the initialVisibilityDelay was the cleanest and simplest. Also saves us money since we're not using the scheduler.

Comment: Glad to help, this should accomplish your goal with the least of efforts.

Comment: This should be the answer here. I have a similar need, and there are so many convoluted options with sleeping threads, timers with short intervals, etc. All which require more work. With the `initialVisibilityDelay` I can drop a series of delayed messages in queue for a recurring webjob vs having to try to trigger the webjob to run at various times. Thanks for the info @lopezbertoni.

Comment: @dsghi Glad that my answer was helpful!

Comment: We have been using this initialVisibilityDelay property as well, but just "discovered" a limitation with it: You cannot delay the queue message for more than 7 days from the current time! This was a dealbreaker for us, but it may be possible to work around it by throwing another message back on the queue if not enough time has passed (if you need more than 1 week)

Answer (score 1):

To invoke a WebJob from your Website,is not good idea rather than you can add the WebJob code inside your Website and simply call that code. you can still easily use the WebJob SDK from inside your Website.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples

we wouldn't recommend to invoke the WebJob from your Website is that the invocation contains a secret you rather not store on your Website (deployment credentials).

**Recommendation**: 
To separate WebJob and Website code, the best thing to do is to communicate using a **queue**, the WebJob listens on the **queue** and the Website pushes the request to the **queue**.